# How to index a dataframe with a user-defined string?

Tags: database, dataframe, csv, julia

Assumptions: I have a Julia DataFrame with a column titled `article_id`.

Normally, I can declare a DataFrame using some syntax like `df = DataFrame(CSV.File(dataFileName; delim = ","))`. If I wanted to get the column pertaining to a known attribute, I could do something like `df.article_id`. I could also index that specific column by doing `df."article_id"`.

However, if I created a string and assigned it to the value of `article_id`, such as `str = "article_id"`, I cannot index the dataframe via `df.str`: I get an error by doing so. This makes sense, as `str` is not an attribute of the DataFrame, yet the value of `str` *is* an attribute of the DataFrame. How can I index the DataFrame to get the column corresponding to the value of `str`? I'm looking for some syntax similar to `df.valueof(str)`.

Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DataFrames.jl manual's "Getting started" page](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/latest/man/getting_started/#The-DataFrame-Type):

> Columns can be directly (i.e. without copying) accessed via df.col, df."col", df[!, :col] or df[!, "col"]. The two latter syntaxes are more flexible as they allow passing a variable holding the name of the column, and not only a literal name.

So you can write `df[!, str]`, and that will be equivalent to `df.article_id` if `str == "article_id"`.

The [Indexing section](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/latest/man/working_with_dataframes/#Indexing-syntax) of the manual goes into even more detail, for when you need more advanced types of indexing or want a deeper understanding of the options.

Answer (score 0):

For an additional reference. When you write:
`df.colname`
it is equivalent to writing `getproperty(df, :colname)`. Therefore if you have column name stored in the `str` variable you can write `getproperty(df, str)`.

However, as Sundar R noted it is usually more convenient to use indexing instead of property access. Two most common patterns are `df[!, str]` which is equivalent to `getproperty(df, str)` and gets you a column without copying it and `df[:, str]` which gets you a copy of a column.